# I want to add waitview in same view using storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, storyboard

I have created a view in same view controller.
And just need to set hidden true or false.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)addWaitView
{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:loadView];
    [loadView setHidden:NO];

}

- (void)removeWaitView
{
    [loadView setHidden:YES];
}

- (IBAction)actionUpdate:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"actionUpdate");

    [self addWaitView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(callAllMethods) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

}
```

The method is called, addWaitView, but can not see the waitview in view.
the view is attached from IBOutlet

```
IBOutlet UIView *loadView;
```

to call remove waitview, I use the code below in my method

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeWaitView) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Need help

Comment: can you add code for callAllMethods

Comment: Maybe you could set it as unhidden before brining it to the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, after so much confusion,

All need to set "**Restoration ID**" in storyboard same as named in **IBOutlet**

Set

```
[self performSelector:@selector(callAllMethods) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
```

Now its working fine.

Comment: nice question, answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[self bringSubviewToFront:[loadView superview]]; 

[[loadView superView] bringSubviewToFront:loadView];
[loadView setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Tried this... But same behaviour as i mentioned above